# how can get the contact image of person from address book by passing the mobile number as an argument

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

how can we get the contact image of person from address book by passing the mobile number as an argument. I don't want to open the address book.

I have one Image Well and other-one text field with number and one button for getting the image.

I just want to put 10 digit number into text field. and press the button then I want to get the thumbnail image of the person from the address book that have this number.
I just want to get the thumbnail image of person from mobile number that i m passing from my UIView.but i don't want go open the address book and select any contact from list into my UIView page.

please any one help me for the code. i am new in iphone development.

Answer (score 2):

Check the sample for getting the image from phone number

```
NSString phoneNumber = @"yourPhoneNumber";
UIImage *myContactImage;
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

    // Get all contacts in the addressbook
    NSArray *allPeople = (__bridge NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

    for (id person in allPeople) {
        // Get all phone numbers of a contact
        ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)(person), kABPersonPhoneProperty);

        // If the contact has multiple phone numbers, iterate on each of them
        for (int i = 0; i &lt; ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers); i++) {
            NSString *phone = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, i);

            // Remove all formatting symbols that might be in both phone number being compared
            NSCharacterSet *toExclude = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/.()- "];
            phone = [[phone componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:toExclude] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
            phoneNumber = [[phoneNumber componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:toExclude] componentsJoinedByString: @""];

            if ([phone isEqualToString:phoneNumber]) {
                NSData *contactImageData = (NSData*)ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
                myContactImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:contactImageData];
                break;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Sumanth, but here is showing some big memory leaksMSRCallMeBack(861,0xac5822c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=2097152) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
MSRCallMeBack(861,0xac5822c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=2097152) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
MSRCallMeBack(861,0xac5822c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=2097152) failed (error code=12)